# How to add simple product to cart instead of configurable product in Magento2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, addtocart, simple-product, plugin

I would like to **add the simple product** equivalent of the selected configurable product **to the cart**.
I would like to solve that **with a plugin**.
I would like to know **where should I intercept the code**, and **how can I get the simple product** if I have the configurable product **with the selected attributes**.

So what I did until now:

```
class Cart
{

protected $quote;
protected $request;
protected $configurableproduct;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $configurableproduct
){
    $this->quote = $checkoutSession->getQuote();
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->configurableproduct = $configurableproduct;
}

public function beforeAddProduct($subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
{

    $paramsData = $this->request->getParams();
    foreach($paramsData as $pId=>$param){ echo "booo";
            $params['product'] = $paramsData['product'][$pId];
            $params['super_attribute'] = $paramsData['super_attribute'][$pId];
        }
        var_dump($params);
    }
    $productId = (int)$this->request->getParam('product', 0);


    return array($productInfo, $requestInfo);
}
}
```

But it does not work...

It must be something with the `foreach` loop, because if I comment that out, the code runs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, this is my solution:

```
class Cart
{
protected $quote;
protected $request;
protected $configurableproduct;
protected $urlinterface;
protected $productrepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $configurableproduct,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlinterface,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productrepository
){
    $this->quote = $checkoutSession->getQuote();
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->configurableproduct = $configurableproduct;
    $this->urlinterface = $urlinterface;
    $this->productrepository = $productrepository;
}

public function beforeAddProduct($subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
{

    $paramsData = $this->request->getParams();
    $productId = $paramsData['product'];
    $product = $this->productrepository->getById($productId);
    if ($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
        $attributes = $paramsData['super_attribute'];

        $new_product = $this->configurableproduct->getProductByAttributes($attributes, $product);
        $new_productId = $new_product->getID();

        $productInfo = $new_productId;
    }

    return array($productInfo, $requestInfo);
}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the customer price in simple product.
I've try to set the normal price to 0.00 and customer price to 10.00 and when i add product to card, it render 0.00 but not 10.00 in minicart.
http://prntscr.com/o6qqng
http://prntscr.com/o6qqzm
http://prntscr.com/o6qr6c